# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel despite working in the same place

Tags: php, laravel

There are numerous questions concerning my problem but it's never been the case I encounter, so here my code:

```
 <td>{{ $note->title}}</td>
 <td>{{ App\User::where('id', $note->user)->first()->name }}</td>
 <td>{{ date("d.m.Y H:i:s", strtotime($note->created_at)) }}</td>
 <td>{{ date("d.m.Y H:i:s", strtotime($note->updated_at)) }}</td>
```

Everything works fine so far, except for

```
<td>{{ App\User::where('id', $note->user)->first()->name }}</td>
```

I figured out that the problem is `$note->user` and it throws

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   Trying to get property of non-object

which doesn't make ANY sense to me since `$note->title` above and `$note->created_at` work like a charm. Any ideas?

Comment: Just FYI, if `$note` is an Eloquent model the `created_at` and `updated_at` should `Carbon` instances so you should be able to call format on them e.g. `$note->updated_at->format('d.m.Y H:i:s')`. http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: @RossWilson Thank you very much. Wasn't aware of that!

Comment: Please may you show the `Route` or controller method that returns this view?

Answer (score 2):

You should always check if a user exists:

```
$user = App\User::where('id', $note->user)->first();
```

Then in the view:

```
{{ is_null($user) ? 'No user with specified ID' : $user->name }}
```

Also, it's a terrible idea to use Eloquent in a view.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where `$user = App\User::where('id', $note->user)->first();` should be put and why it's a terrible idea to use Eloquent in a view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the existence of user before asking for its name.

Also you can leverage Eloquent relationships which will remove the user retrieval from your view.

Add a user relationship to the `Note` model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'user');
}
```

Then in your view you can call `$note->user` which will return a `App\User` instance if found or else `null`.

So to print user's name

```
 <td>{{ $note->user ? $note->user->name : '' }}</td>
```